# Pandas column renaming according to day of year

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a remote-sensed time series data stored in a Pandas data frame. The original name of the columns are 2 strings `res_final 001`...`res_final 365`. I would like to rename them keeping only the DOY part. It stored in a tuple `('res_final', '001')`.

What I tried:

`df.rename(columns = {'final_res':None})` resulted `('', '001')`

How can I rename it to keep only the second part of the tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the columns, modify the list, and assign it to df.columns:

```
import pandas as pd

#Create a sample dataframe
columns = ['ABC',1]+[f"res_final {str(r).zfill(3)}" for r in range(1,5)]
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=columns)

#    ABC  1  res_final 001  res_final 002  res_final 003  res_final 004
# 0    1  2              3              4              5              6

new_columns = [str(c).split(' ')[1] if 'res' in str(c) else c for c in df.columns]
#['ABC', 1, '001', '002', '003', '004']

df.columns = new_columns
#   ABC  1  001  002  003  004
#0    1  2    3    4    5    6
```